# How to install custom typing after creating in a separate project using Typescript + Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm-install, typescript-typings

I am working on an application for node.js spread across four separate webstorm gui projects.  Ideally, I would like to create a module-plugin library containing a set of code that needs to be shared by the other other projects, i.e., GenericRepository, etc.  I implemented a module-plugin following the documentation outlined on the typescript website; module-plugin.d.ts(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html).  I ran the tsconfig file to compile to a dist folder and the compilation completed successfully.  So far so good.

When I try to install using "npm install --save @types/../GenericRepository", for example, I am getting an error stating the folder does not contain a package.json file.  This makes no sense as there is a package.json file in the folder.  I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Here is the package.json file for the GenericRepository folder:

```
{
  "name": "GenericRepository",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "typings": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "grunt": "grunt"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/express-jwt": "0.0.34",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongodb": "^2.1.41",
    "@types/mongoose": "^4.7.9",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.10",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-ts": "^6.0.0-beta.15",
    "grunt-tslint": "^4.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Here is the tsconfig.json file for the GenericRepository project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["ES6"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "noLib": false
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/@types",
    "typings.json"
    //"typings/global",
    //"typings/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```